# How to quickly add a debug border in Tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

When debugging traditional CSS I often use a red border to highlight a certain element on my page: `border: 1px solid red`.

In Tailwind it's quite cumbersome to type something like `className="border-2 border-solid border-red"` over and over again. I'd rather write something like `className="debug"`. Is a shorthand like that possible in Tailwind?

Comment: You can just add the `debug` class to your `main.css` and add the border classes with `@apply`. 

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Add a custom `utility` to your tailwind's CSS file.

[Link to the docs.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-custom-utilities)

You can use plain `CSS` or the `@apply` method.

---

CSS:

```html
<div class="debug">Text</div>
```

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .debug {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

[Tailwind-play link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/jSNGkYUOu2?file=css)

---

@apply:

```html
<div class="debug">Text</div>
```

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .debug {
    @apply border-[1px] border-red-500
  }
}
```

[Tailwind-play link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/nAQnnAP7JW?file=css)